# PDF to EPUB tool for articles

Tags: pdf, document-converter, epub

I read quite a few articles per month. I always have problems because I'm always walking with a bunch of printed papers and I have trouble looking for highlighted parts.

Until, last month. Last month, I figured out that EPUB files integrated awesomely with iBooks, allowing me to highlight stuff and easily retrieve/search later.

My problem now is to find articles in EPUB. They just don't exists. So I took a shot using some online tools. Although they work for regular textual books (such as regular full-page literature, e.g. normal books), they do not work as expected for PDF articles (usually with 2 columns of text).

Anyone know a good tool to do this?

Comment: Have you used calibre? The issue you will have is due to the lack of structure information in pdf's once they have been generated in the final format.

Answer (score 2):

I second Calibre, but results are mediocre. Nothing I have tried is good enough though.

An alternative is cropping the margins from pdf files, so that they become bearable on the e-reader's screen. However, I have been using a Kindle in the past, and a Kobo currently, and neither was adequate for reading journal articles.

Finally, I just got a cheap 9.7" tablet, which gets the job done. In this case, the Xodo app even crops margins automatically.